# Windows XP/Vista/7 Check Battery Charge from CMD?

Tags: windows, battery, power

How can I get the battery status in windows? On Linux it is as simple as `acpi -b` but in Windows this simple task seems impossible.

`powercfg -energy` can get all kinds of all information, but won't output something as simple as the charge level. I just need something simple which I can use for some scripts.

Answer (score 19):

You can use WMIC, e.g. `WMIC Path Win32_Battery` for a full table of info, or `WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining` etc to get a specific detail

Comment: @PSYU If this answer solved your question, click the checkmark next to it.

Comment: You can also use: `powercfg /batteryreport /output C:\Location\FileName.html` This isn't exactly the best for scripts and offers more than simple battery charge level but offers a lot more information regarding health, battery charge history, degradation, etc... However despite the fact that it doesn't display simple info, it is user friendly to read which may pertain to your script and can also be loaded directly after creation of the .`html` which is easily scriptable. This is actually my preferred method for the script that I use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. powercfg also requires admin privileges to run whereas WMIC does not.

Answer (score -1):

for Windows 10, type:

> powercfg/BATTERYREPORT
>
> battery-report.html

answer is the last item listed under "Recent usage".