# Is it possible to show the battery level of an RDP client inside the host?

Tags: windows, laptop, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, battery

I have a Windows 10 Pro VM that I often connect to from a Windows 10 laptop. I connect using vanilla Microsoft Remote Desktop Client. Because I full-screen the remote session so often, I sometimes don't notice my battery level draining.

Is it possible to show the battery level of my laptop *inside* the virtual machine I connect to?

Comment: Maybe: `WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get BatteryStatus`

Comment: See here too just in case: https://superuser.com/questions/333329/windows-xp-vista-7-check-battery-charge-from-cmd

Comment: I'm trying to see the laptop's battery gauge inside the VM I rdp to.

Comment: @Facebook Excellent approach, but you may want to add a /NODE:"systemName" switch to the right spot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't find anything that would do this, either, so I [started a new project](https://github.com/Field-Effect-LLC/RDP-BattMon) on GitHub to create a Microsoft RDP client add-in for battery reporting.

Check the [releases](https://github.com/Field-Effect-LLC/RDP-BattMon/releases) page for Windows binaries, if you prefer not to compile from the source, and follow the [instructions](https://github.com/Field-Effect-LLC/RDP-BattMon/blob/master/README.md) for installation.

Comment: This is great! I will be running this immediately!

Comment: I don't have much rep. but this is so awesome it is well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I haven't used Windows in a long time, so I haven't tested this. That said, it should work.

- Install [8gadgetpack](http://8gadgetpack.net/) to enable support to "Windows gadgets".

  <sup>(Needed for Windows versions higher than 7)</sup>
- Install the ["Battery Meter" gadget](http://addgadgets.com/battery_meter/).
- Activate the gadget, right-click and set it to "always on top".

Comment: This would do the job, but I was hoping for something that would integrate into the Windows power meter.

Comment: If the virtual machine is in another computer you need to use a solution like this, there is no way you can do it with the Windows power meter (because that would need built a networked solution *just for this*, which is a very corner case).

Comment: I was afraid of this. The WMIC commands above look hopeful. I just had the linux-centric dream there would be someway to hack it together.